# How to reduce MySQL Server CPU usage or load?

Tags: linux, mysql, cpu-usage, optimization

How to reduce MySQL Server CPU usage or load ?

Here is my.cnf :

```
skip-name-resolve
disable_log_bin

innodb_buffer_pool_size=200GB

innodb_log_file_size=25GB
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=64
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=120
innodb_file_per_table=1


innodb_io_capacity=5000
innodb_write_io_threads=32
innodb_read_io_threads=32
innodb_thread_concurrency=512
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0

slow_query_log=1
slow_query_log_file="/var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log"
long_query_time=1

transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED

bulk_insert_buffer_size=256M
max_allowed_packet=64M
max_heap_table_size=256M
ft_min_word_len=2
ft_stopword_file=/var/lib/mysql/stopwords
max_connections=1024
max_user_connections=1024
max_connect_errors=999999999

tmp_table_size=128M
table_open_cache=5000
wait_timeout=10800
thread_cache_size=400
group_concat_max_len=4194304

join_buffer_size=32M
key_buffer_size=2GB
read_buffer_size=8M
sort_buffer_size=8M
read_rnd_buffer_size=16M
myisam_sort_buffer_size=600M

delayed_insert_limit=100
delayed_insert_timeout=300
delayed_queue_size=1000000

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Comment: How much RAM?  Please find the 'worst' query via the slowlog -- [_SlowLog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog)

Comment: Q: What's your current CPU utilization (have you looked in "top", for example)?  Q: If CPU "spikes", have you identified the query?  Q: Have you looked at [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execution-plan-information.html} for that query?  Q (per linuxpro): How much RAM do you have?

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider to reduce cpu usage or load in [mysql] section of my.cnf

```
read_rnd_buffer_size=32K  # from 16M to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS
read_buffer_size=1M  # from 8M to reduce handler_read_next RPS
innodb_thread_concurrency=0  # from 512 to allow OS to manage the limit
max_connect_errors=10  # from 999999999 to aggravate hackers/crackers after 10 break in attempts
```

View profile for contact info, posting requested additional information will allow additional suggestions.